# How to Play GIF on click audio play button

Tags: javascript, html, css, gif

I want that whenever anyone plays the audio then only gif play..
here what I  tried...

```js
number = 0;
var animations = ['https://static.wixstatic.com/media/6b2a99_687dc4cb09bc42bdb230d1c8ce7815a4~mv2.gif',
  'https://static.wixstatic.com/media/6b2a99_687dc4cb09bc42bdb230d1c8ce7815a4~mv2.gif',
  'https://static.wixstatic.com/media/6b2a99_687dc4cb09bc42bdb230d1c8ce7815a4~mv2.gif'
];


function character() {

  image = document.getElementById('1BoXzCv8EbZ5BDnb47T31lPM1lKdne7wG');
  image.src = animations[number];

}
```

```html
<div class="board">
<img src="https://blogger.googleusercontent.com/img/a/AVvXsEhUIEQv7m_0HrLkcEDQURyV74eGEO8ZDW0LhhyFbK72BBXm9S0BolRB0V82i7RvX5S83j1QPOYazQlbUp8p9S5xSnlMNIpQGwJdKlmwCiPc8sHMqO8dPgYpstyejRK9rKeWNlofjOhTQGcfyk3Jt_1YqAezHYyRBDJiaGYD1R5O9mrdzaQKzDAc0Pe2oA=s16000" alt="cassete" width="300" height="200" id="1BoXzCv8EbZ5BDnb47T31lPM1lKdne7wG" onclick="character();"/>
<audio class="splplayer" controls="controls" id="audio_player" preload="metadata">
<source src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&amp;id=1BoXzCv8EbZ5BDnb47T31lPM1lKdne7wG"></source></audio></div>
```

Don't know where the error occurs.... here gif is playing on clicking on it not on clicking the audio play button

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/serii/rjf5qnb9/1/